# Употребление слов "штука" и "экземпляр"

Tags: грамотная-речь, трудности

У нас, в типографии, при оформлении документов возникает вопрос: как нужно писать "Тираж 1000 экземпляров" или "1000 штук"? В каких случаях используется одно или другое слово?

Answer (score 1):

Слова штука и экземпляр многозначные, являются синонимами в значении "отдельный предмет из ряда подобных". О печатном или рукописном тексте принято говорить "экземпляр".

Comment: Благодарю!